# How to overcome virtual package already provided in effect, but not in practice

Tags: linux, python, yum, rpm, dependencies

I'm trying to install package X, which is dependent on the virtual package named `python`.

I have `python27` installed, and I *know* that my desired package X works fine with this version; however `python27` does not provide the requisite virtual package `python`.

If I search my repos for packages that provide `python`, I find that only `python26` does.

What should I do?

1. Somehow convince yum that package X really depends on `python27` and not `python`;
2. Somehow convince yum that `python` has been provided by `python27`;
3. Somehow convince yum that, for package X only, `python` is provided by `python27`; or
4. Somehow convince yum that it can proceed with the installation of package X without worrying about the missing dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Create package `my-python-bridge`, which:

```
Name: my-python-bridge
Requires: python27
Provides: python
```

Comment: So, this is basically option 2?  I like it—very clean.  But what pros/cons would there be?

Comment: Yes. The only cons is that you have to create your own package. Not big deal if you already done some. 1-2 hours if you are doing that for the first time.